# onClick not working

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

My button with id "jump-button" is not working at all. Whenever it is clicked nothing will happen. (I have added a alert(); to the onclick attribute so I know when the button is working.

The other two buttons (next and prev) are working absolutely fine.

```
<body>

<div id="fact">Fact #1: In 2002, the most popular boat name in the U.S. was Liberty</div>
<input id="next" type="image" src="images/next-button.png" name="next" value="Next" onClick="num++;document.getElementById('fact').innerHTML=getFact(num);"/>
<input id="prev" type="image" src="images/prev-button.png" name="previous" value="Prev" onClick="num--;document.getElementById('fact').innerHTML=getFact(num);"/>

<p id="jump-text">Jump To Fact #</p>

<input id="textarea" type="text" name="factNumber" />
<input id="jump-button" type="image" src="images/jump-button.png" name="jump" value="Jump" onClick="alert();num = document.getElementById('textarea').value;document.getElementById('fact').innerHTML='getFact(num);"/>

</body>
```

External JS File (it has been inported in the HTML header)

```
facts = [element1, element2, ... wayy too many elements to have them all here];
var num = 1;

function getFact (num){
    return 'Fact #' + num + ' ' + facts[num-1]; 
}
```

As you can see, this is a very simple app being built (something that just runs through various interesting facts). I am fairly new to javascript, so please excuse me if I made a very blatant error.

My CSS file is very nice and simple too, I doubt it it causing the trouble, but if it is required I will shot it upon request.

Lastly, the rest of the html `<head>` is also very simple (only consists of some meta data, title, css and javascript imports).

If anyone needs more information to help me get the "jump" button working, please ask.

Comment: @Sani Yes there is, http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_input.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a stray `'` in your inline `onClick` attribute.

```
// ---------------------------------------------------v
onClick="...document.getElementById('fact').innerHTML='getFact(num);"
```

Comment: Yikes, looks like I need some sleep (or a more colourful IDE). I looked over that line a bajillion times and couldn't find the bug. I am the utmost grateful to you!